# Rosservice Kinetic vs Melodic

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently working on a project that was left partly complete by someone else, a while ago. The project is written with ROS Kinetic, but I'd like to make it compatible with melodic too (running on ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 respectively, both on VMs). I've had some issues, though. Rosservice commands in particular don't work with Melodic, while they do work with Kinetic. I get errors saying "String has no len()" (this is a std_msgs String) but I never called len() in my code! Are there any differences between the implementation of Rosservice that I should be aware of? Sorry if it's something simple; I'm completely new to ROS.

The code:

```
import rospy
import ethernetcommunicator
import serialcommunicator
from std_msgs.msg import Bool
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from std_msgs.msg import String
from mswrapper.srv import *

cm = serialcommunicator.Serialcommunicator()

def send_command_callback(data):
    return cm.send_command(data.data)

def set_speed_callback(data):
    cm.motor_jog(data.data)

def handle_send_command(req):
    controller_response = cm.send_command(str(req.command)[6:])
    if not controller_response:
        controller_response = ""
    return SendCommandResponse(String(controller_response))

def loop():
    input_1_pub = rospy.Publisher('mswrapper/input_1', Bool, queue_size=10)
    rospy.Subscriber('mswrapper/set_speed', Float64, set_speed_callback)
    rospy.Subscriber('mswrapper/send_command', String, send_command_callback)
    rospy.init_node('asciicom', anonymous=False)
    send_command_service = rospy.Service('mswrapper/send_command', SendCommand, handle_send_command)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        input_1_pub.publish(cm.get_input_1())
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        loop()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

The error message is quite odd:

```
ERROR: Unable to send request. One of the fields has an incorrect type: 

     <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'object of type 'String' has no len()' when writing 'data: 'mtr on''
```

srv file:

```
std_msgs/String command
    string data
---
std_msgs/String result
    string data
```

As you can see, there is no line number provided, only an error and a printout of my .srv file.

Meanwhile, on the node I'm running this from, I get another error message:

```
[ERROR] [numbers]: incoming connection failed: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
```

So I have no idea where the error is coming from since I don't get a line number or even a file where this is taking place. Any help would be much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327534/rosservice-kinetic-vs-melodic/) by [Qwertazertyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/43810/qwertazertyl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2019-07-02**:
Please describe how rosservice "doesn't work". Please check in with the support guideline  http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do

**Comment by [Qwertazertyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/43810/qwertazertyl/) on 2019-07-02**:
Edited, is this ok?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-02**:
Can you please update your question with your code?

**Comment by [Qwertazertyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/43810/qwertazertyl/) on 2019-07-03**:
Code has been added

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-03**:
Does it really say

```
[ERROR] [some numbers]:
```

? I've never seen any error like this. Can you please update your question with the *full* error (not redacted) and the *full* code (not abbreviated).

**Comment by [Qwertazertyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/43810/qwertazertyl/) on 2019-07-03**:
The error numbers change every time...

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-03**:
Correct, but my point was more along the lines of what else are we missing from the error, if anything?

**Comment by [Qwertazertyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/43810/qwertazertyl/) on 2019-07-03**:
That's the full error. I'll update the whole program if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> def handle_send_command(req):
> ```

```
    controller_response = cm.send_command(str(req.command)[6:])
```

this is most likely your problem: `req.command` is a `std_msgs.String`, not a `str`.

A `std_msgs.String` contains a `data` field, which *is* a `str`.

So you'll probably want to do something like:

```
 def handle_send_command(req):
    controller_response = cm.send_command(str(req.command.data)[6:])
```

Additionally:

```
def loop():
    ...
    send_command_service = rospy.Service('mswrapper/send_command', SendCommand, handle_send_command)
```

Are you (re)creating `Service` servers in a loop? That's probably not something you want to do.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-03**:
PS: I'm also uncertain *why* you are using `std_msgs/String` in your custom `.srv`: why not use the `string` type directly for the `command` and `result` fields?

PPS: using some other than a `string` may actually be better, as a `string` can contain any arbitrary string, not just valid ones.

And PPPS: I'm not sure how this would've ever worked. Afaik this hasn't changed between Kinetic and Melodic.

**Comment by [Qwertazertyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/43810/qwertazertyl/) on 2019-07-03**:
I tried changing to req.command.data but still get the same "String has no len()" error. Also, I tried adding some print statements in handle_send_command but nothing appears.

**Comment by [Qwertazertyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/43810/qwertazertyl/) on 2019-07-03**:
And should I just move the service definition out of loop? Or should I put it in main, another function, etc?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

std_msgs/String does not have a method 'len'.

std_msgs/String has a field named 'data' and this field is a python string, where you can use 'len'.

Fire up a python interpreter:

```
>>> from std_msgs.msg import String
>>> s = String()
>>> len(s.data)
0
>>> len(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'String' has no len()
```

So look for the place where the exception is thrown, and correct the issue.
It has probably nothing to do with kinetic vs melodic, you are maybe just hitting a different execution path in the code.

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qwertazertyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/43810/qwertazertyl/) on 2019-07-03**:
The thing is, I didn't call len() anywhere in my code, and I don't have a line number to work with. That's why I thought it was melodic calling len() because of some new feature that kinetic didn't have